# How to re-size the text generated by Barbecue API?

Tags: java, resize, barcode, barbecue

I am trying to generate a barcode using the Barbecue API. The problem i am facing is that while i try to re-size the barcode the code in textual form which is printed below the barcode remains the same size. I need to decrease its side also. I have tried the following code :

Part 1:Original Size Barcode

```
Barcode b = BarcodeFactory.create2of7("4561");
b.setBarHeight(5);
b.setBarWidth(1);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(b);
if (job.printDialog())
{
        job.print();
}
```

Part 2: Code for resizing

```
Barcode b = BarcodeFactory.create2of7("4561");
b.setBarHeight(5);
b.setBarWidth(1);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPrintable(b);
if (job.printDialog())
{
job.print();
}
```

Below is the output image of the barcode:

[image: Output of both the parts]

As you can see the code remains the same size. How can i decrease its size? Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell how did you do this resize, I see the both codes are the same in part 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class `BarCodeBuilder` instead if `Barcode`
just like

```
  BarCodeBuilder b=new BarCodeBuilder();
  b.setCodeText("abc123");
  b.setSymbologyType(Symbology.Codabar);
  b.setResolution(new Resolution(50f,40f,ResolutionMode.Graphics));
```

It works for me...

Comment: which version of Barbecue are you using?

Comment: I thinks Aspose is a paid, is it? I need open source.

Comment: Downvoted. The answer is based in other library while the question explicity asks for a Barbecue based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Barcode b;

b.setFont(null);

This would help you get the font size to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should to use Barcode.setFont() method to set the font size

[reference](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sourceforge/barbecue/Barcode.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29)

Answer (score 0):

Since **net.sourceforge.barbecue.Barcode**'s getFont() return a good old null, you either have to construct a **Font** object, or get one from somewhere, and change its size to your liking, then assign it to the **Barcode** with .setFont().

It works for me with this code:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
Barcode b = BarcodeFactory.createCode128("Hello");
Font deriveFont = g2d.getFont().deriveFont(8.5f); //copy of original Font with given size
b.setFont(deriveFont);
```

The **Font** size is not given in pixels! I believe its dimension is points.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked:

```
    Barcode barcode;
    barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128B(Integer.toString("my barcode"));
    barcode.setBarHeight(40);
    barcode.setBarWidth(2);
    barcode.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 10));
```